# Initialise and return struct on one line

Tags: c

Is it possible to initialise and return a struct on one line in C?

```
typedef struct {
    long tau;
    float probability;
} pitch_result;

pitch_result f(){
    pitch_result result = {0, 0};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `pitch_result result = {0, 0}; return result;`? Remove the newline.

Comment: maybe `return (pitch_result){0, 0};`?

Comment: @Eraklon Yes that is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could just return a *compound literal* like this:

```
return (pitch_result) {0, 0};
```

This can also be used with assignments, which should not be mixed up with initializations.

This would not work:

```
pitch_result x;
x = {0, 0};
```

But this would

```
pitch_result x;
x = (pitch_result) {0, 0};
```

A compound literal looks like a cast, but it's not. For instance, it is an lvalue. This does compile (but I fail to see how it is useful):

```
(pitch_result){0, 0} = (pitch_result) {1, 1};
```